# Copying text from screen with robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Is it possible to copy text from website with robot framework? I need to make robot fill out a form with our website, and then copy the saved forms title.

Every title is unique and visible in the screen after the form is saved.

I'd like to then use the title text to test our search function.

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick!

```
${Variable_name} = Get Text <location>

Set Suite Variable  ${Variable_name_to_use_later}  ${Variable_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

${variable} =  Get Text  ${locator}

In my case such a construction did not return a value until I added "Scroll Element Into View" keyword from SeleniumLibrary

This is how I had to do:

```
Scroll Element Into View  ${locator} 
${variable} =  Get Text  ${locator}
```